# List Schema - URL Syntax

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I ran acrossed this a couple months ago and did not save the link anywhere, unfortunately.

Basically, there is a URl syntax to extract a Sharepoint Lists basic schema that exports it to the browser in XML format.  It gives the basic information for the field and views of the list.

Resolution:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/05/01/getting-xml-data-from-a-sharepoint-list-the-easy-way.aspx

You just have to put in the right context of words to get the result you need.

Comment: guess we cant use LMGTFY here...oh well....search keywords were: "sharepoint retrieve list xml schema"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everyone else's sake:

```
http://<PATH TO SITE>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={GUID}
```

The list GUID can be found by going to the List Settings, then pulling out the GUID from the URL.

Comment: Does this work with SharePoint Online 2013? I'm trying it but it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this: http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/01/21/introduction-to-querying-lists-with-rest-and-listdata-svc-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Not sure if it's what you are after..

Comment: yeah that first pic is...not sure if 2007 has the svc but i will look at it in a just a second and see if it reports correctly.

Comment: nope SP2007 doesnt utilize that service if RSS feeds are not enabled.  The result is similar but its not the same.  If i remember right it was a single asmx page with querystring data inputed to produce the XML Schema of the List.